# Error when using a CTE in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using an ADO.net source in SSIS and running a query containing a CTE. I am getting the following error:

> NO COLUMN INFORMATION WAS RETURNED BY THE SQL COMMAND

I used `SET NOCOUNT` and `set fmtonly off`, but still no luck.

Can you please help me with resolving this issue?

sample query:

```
with MyCTE as
(
select 
Pno,
jdo,
er,
dtsent,
dtapproved,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Pno,jdo,er ORDER BY dtapproved )  as rn,
Dense_Rank() OVER(ORDER BY Pno,jdo,er )  as rnk  from(
select v1.*,v2.max_jdo as jdo from 
table1 v1 
left join(select Pno,max(jdo) as max_jdo,er from 
 table2
Group by Pno,er ) v2 on
v1.Pno=v2.Pno and
v1.er =v2.er)T
)

select  
c1.Pno ,
c1.jdo, 
c1.er,
case when c1.dtapproved  is null then c1.dtsent else NVL(c2.dtapproved,c1.dtsent) end as Datesent,
c1.dtapproved,
from  MyCTE c1
Left join MyCTE c2
on c1.rn = c2.rn + 1 and c1.rnk=c2.rnk
```

Comment: Providing a code sample would probably be helpful in letting others help you. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What happens if you run the query in SSMS?

Comment: Its works fine in SSMS.Its not working in SSIS

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your query with a dummy resultset like this:

```
IF 1=0
 SELECT 
 '' AS Pno ,
 '' AS jdo, 
 '' AS er,
 GETDATE() AS Datesent,
 GETDATE() AS dtapproved;
ELSE
 with MyCTE as (... the query that works in SSMS)
```

Use dummy data that represents the correct data types of the expected results.   That's why I used GETDATE() to create dummy data for columns that looked like they should be `datetime` data.

Also double check that you don't have that comma after `c1.dtapproved` that you have in the example posted, because that would cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking there are various workarounds to using ctes:

first of all why not oledb command use.
If you have already used fmtonly and nocount you can use EXEC WITH RESULT SETS:
[execute result sets t-sql](http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-execute-result-sets)

or what you can do is run the full command in a proc, load up a temp table and use it as a source.
Moreover one can also use script component where you run the query as a sqlcommand.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Oracle OLEDB driver to version 12.2.

See full answer @ [Oracle CTE to SQL Server Using SSIS OLE DB Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210006/53380).